# how to relpace a array to the diagonal of numpy array python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[0.7513,  0.6991,    0.5472,    0.2575],
          [0.2551,  0.8909,    0.1386,    0.8407],
          [0.5060,  0.9593,    0.1493,    0.2543],
          [0.5060,  0.9593,    0.1493,    0.2543]])
y = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
```

How to replace the diagonal of X with y. We can write a loop but any faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast and reliable method is `np.einsum`:

```
>>> diag_view = np.einsum('ii->i', X)
```

This creates a view of the diagonal:

```
>>> diag_view
array([0.7513, 0.8909, 0.1493, 0.2543])
```

This view is writable:

```
>>> diag_view[None] = y
>>> X                                                                                                               
array([[1.    , 0.6991, 0.5472, 0.2575],                                                                            
       [0.2551, 2.    , 0.1386, 0.8407],                                                                            
       [0.506 , 0.9593, 3.    , 0.2543],                                                                            
       [0.506 , 0.9593, 0.1493, 4.    ]])
```

This works for contiguous and non-contiguous arrays and is very fast:

```
contiguous:
loop          21.146424998732982
diag_indices  2.595232878000388
einsum        1.0271988900003635
flatten       1.5372659160002513

non contiguous:
loop          20.133818001340842
diag_indices  2.618005960001028
einsum        1.0305795049989683
Traceback (most recent call last): <- flatten does not work here
...
```

How does it work? Under the hood `einsum` does an advanced version of @Julien's trick: It adds the strides of `arr`:

```
>>> arr.strides
(3200, 16)
>>> np.einsum('ii->i', arr).strides
(3216,)
```

One can convince oneself that this will always work as long as arr is organized in strides, which is the case for numpy arrays.

While this use of `einsum` is pretty neat it is also almost impossible to find if one doesn't know. So spread the word!

Code to recreate the timings and the crash:

```
import numpy as np

n = 100
arr = np.zeros((n, n))
replace = np.ones(n)

def loop():
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i,i] = replace[i]

def other():
    l = len(arr)
    arr.shape = -1
    arr[::l+1] = replace
    arr.shape = l,l

def di():
    arr[np.diag_indices(arr.shape[0])] = replace

def es():
    np.einsum('ii->i', arr)[...] = replace

from timeit import timeit
print('\ncontiguous:')
print('loop         ', timeit(loop, number=1000)*1000)
print('diag_indices ', timeit(di))
print('einsum       ', timeit(es))
print('flatten      ', timeit(other))

arr = np.zeros((2*n, 2*n))[::2, ::2]
print('\nnon contiguous:')
print('loop         ', timeit(loop, number=1000)*1000)
print('diag_indices ', timeit(di))
print('einsum       ', timeit(es))
print('flatten      ', timeit(other))
```

Comment: Very insightful!

Answer (score 3):

This should be pretty fast (especially for bigger arrays, for your example it's about twice slower):

```
arr = np.zeros((4,4))
replace = [1,2,3,4]

l = len(arr)
arr.shape = -1
arr[::l+1] = replace
arr.shape = l,l
```

Test on bigger array:

```
n = 100
arr = np.zeros((n,n))
replace = np.ones(n)

def loop():
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        arr[i,i] = replace[i]

def other():
    l = len(arr)
    arr.shape = -1
    arr[::l+1] = replace
    arr.shape = l,l

%timeit(loop())
%timeit(other())

14.7 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
1.55 µs ± 24.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: is there any different if the replace = array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4 ]]) ?  not a list. Thanks

Comment: I believe not, but if if you see some unexpected things you could just do `replace.shape = -1` too...

Answer (score 2):

Use `diag_indices` for a vectorized solution:

```
X[np.diag_indices(X.shape[0])] = y
```

```
array([[1.    , 0.6991, 0.5472, 0.2575],
       [0.2551, 2.    , 0.1386, 0.8407],
       [0.506 , 0.9593, 3.    , 0.2543],
       [0.506 , 0.9593, 0.1493, 4.    ]])
```

Comment: Any idea why this is slower than my hacked method? (3 times slower for n=1000...)

Comment: @Julien Fancy indexing is comparatively expensive. Plain slicing is much cheaper.